# How to destructure CSS variable value in React

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

is it possible to destructure the value of a css variable in React component?
This is the variable, defined in CSS file.

```
--complementary-contrast-alt-2: rgb(77, 179, 229);
```

The idea is to extract the value of that variable and then create a function that would turn a new variable with the result of just the numbers. Result to be like this:

```
const complementaryColor1 = 77, 179, 229;
```

Can this be achieved?

After the conversion, then it would be sent to components CSS, as a prop and be used as a value + opacity, like this.

```
--complementary-contrast-2-translucent: rgba(var(complementaryColor1), 0.6);
```

Comment: What you want to accomplish is absolutely possible, but you can't "destructure" the value.  You can set/get the value in either CSS or JS, but it is a string, so you'd have to use string methods to get at the substring when using JS.